# sent multiple value to innerHTML using javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
function showPrimes(n) {

  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if (!isPrime(i)) continue;
    console.log(i); // a prime
  }
}

function isPrime(n) {
  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if ( n % i == 0) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = showPrimes(5);
```

```html
<div id='res'></div>
```

How to show all showprimes value into the div element it return undefined when using above code

Comment: It shows undefined because `showPrimes` doesn't return anything, so calling it results in the value `undefined`. If you want it to return something, return something (perhaps an array); then that will get assigned to `innerHTML` (after being converted to string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows undefined because `showPrimes` doesn't return anything, so calling it results in the value `undefined`. If you want it to return something, return something (perhaps an array); then that will get assigned to `innerHTML` (after being converted to string). See `***` comments:

```js
function showPrimes(n) {
  const primes = []; // ***
  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if (!isPrime(i)) continue;
    console.log(i);
    primes.push(i); // ***
  }
  return primes; // ***
}

function isPrime(n) {
  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if ( n % i == 0) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = showPrimes(5);
```

```html
<div id="res"></div>
```

That uses the default conversion of array to string, which calls `Array#join`, which uses a comma between the values. You could call `join`  explicitly to do something else, or any of several other tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

There is small issue in your code:

- You are not returning anything from `showPrimes` function that can be actually assigned in 
  `document.getElementById("res").innerHTML`.
- If you directly return a single value from `showPrimes` function then it will not give you the next prime number as `showPrimes` function will get terminated. So, the solution would be to store the prime numbers in an array and then return this array when no prime numbers are left to generate.

```js
var primeArray = [];
function showPrimes(n) {
  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if (!isPrime(i)) continue;
    console.log(i); // a prime
    primeArray.push(i); 
  }
  return primeArray;
}

function isPrime(n) {
  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if ( n % i == 0) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = showPrimes(5);
```

```html
<div id='res'></div>
```